# Firefox failure to connect signed wss://

Tags: firefox, websocket

My firefox addon's WebSocket is working fine on Firefox 43, and latest versions. But I'm getting a few customers(3-4 out of 300) in which I see in Firefox Console that it is not able to connect to url:   "`wss://example.com:8000`"

All are on Windows-10.

When I type this line in the Console :

```
new WebSocket("wss://example.com:8000")
```

It gives the same error.

I also disable Windows firewall and also added exception to all ports both inboud/outbound in Advanced Settings. But it is not working in one PC.

**What could be the problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers not updated with latest ssl certificte.

I just loaded this url in the browser:  `https://example.com:8000` and confirmed the security exception.

**Note**: https NOT wss there.